# Laravel - изменение Form без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: laravel, form

В search.blade есть форма:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['SearchController@ajaxPlayerAuction'],'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'search_players_auction']) !!}
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите имя игрока..." autofocus="autofocus" name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname">
                        <input type="hidden" name="position_id" value="{{\App\Auction::active()->orderBy('finished_at')->get()->first()->type->id}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Найти</button>
                    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Как в методе SearchController@ajaxPlayerAuction добавить к форме сообщение 'Введите больше двух символов'(как варианнт поменять placeholder="Введите имя игрока..." на placeholder="Введите больше двух символов") не перезагружая страницу

Answer (score 1):

На клиенте:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['SearchController@ajaxPlayerAuction'],'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'search_players_auction']) !!}
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите имя игрока..." autofocus="autofocus" name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname">
        <span class="error-message"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="position_id" value="{{\App\Auction::active()->orderBy('finished_at')->get()->first()->type->id}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-3">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Найти</button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}



// on submit
$.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      // do something
    },

    error: function(data) {
        if(data.status==422) {
            $( "#search_players_auction input[type='text']" ).next().text( '' );
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            $( "#search_players_auction input[type='text']" ).removeClass('error');
            $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                $( "input[name='"+key+"']" ).addClass('error');
                $( "input[name='"+key+"']" ).next().text( value[0] );
           });
        }

    }
});
```

В контроллере:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'fullname' => 'required|min:50|max:50',
    ]);

$validator->validate();
```

В языковом файле (resources\lang\ru\validation.php):

```
'attributes' => [
    'fullname'=>'Имя игрока',
];
```